# Error in Alert dialog on this

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-context

This is my code,

```
b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == b3) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Delete")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog d = builder.create();
            d.setTitle("Are you sure");
            d.show();
        }
    }

});

if (!rs.isClosed()) {
    rs.close();
}
name.setText(nam);
email.setText(emai);
```

When I use this code on a delete button an error appear on first "this". How to solve it? How can I use delete confirmation message?

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: is this code in activity or fragment?

Comment: please post full class and stacktrace

Comment: using this is more sensitive and scope specific. You should use actual objects instead of this keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Use context instead of simply "this" reference. Here you can use Activity context, not any other context. For more information visit these links [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) , [AlertDialog.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

For activity:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this);
```

For fragment:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

with

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);
```